# Exchange data between parent component and child component

Tags: angular, service, components

Which is the best way to pass an array of objects from a parent component to child component (the child component will be nested in the parent component)?

After passing the array to the child component, I have to process it to extract information and display in the view (so I have to process the data received within the child component before displaying it).

Comment: Did you read the [whole page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) on this in the docs, or look for other similar questions here on SO?

Comment: Use `@Input` for this. Remember to initialize the array in parent (as empty), so that it won't be undefined when you pass the array in the child tag. Since you need to process the array in the child before displaying, maybe need to use the safe navigation operator in the view. As a sidenote, always share code to clarify your issue, to be able to get some decent answers as well as not getting a bunch of downvotes ;)

Comment: Perfect, it works. If I wanted to pass more than one object?

Comment: @MaurizioRizzo *pass more than one object* - could you elaborate that a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it as an input:

```
<child [data]="myArray"></child>
```

Child class:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];
}
```

This will get you access to the data in `ChildComponent` via `this.data`. To react to changes to the data you can either use `ngOnChanges` or use a `set` and `get` method.

Comment: I have already done so, but inside the "ChildComponent" I can not access in "date: any []"

Comment: If I try to access the application crashes

Comment: @MaurizioRizzo Because it's `data`, not `date` like you said.

Comment: If you provide more info I can help you.

Comment: Perfect, it works. If I wanted to pass more than one object?